# Video Recording with webcam on a webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, video-capture

I have a requirement of recording video via web cam, on my webpage. What are the available plugins for the same. My website is developed using Ruby on Rails framework

Regards,
Pankaj

Answer (score 4):

If an HTML5 solution could be suitable for you, you can take a look to WebRTC (currently supported in Chrome, Firefox and Opera).

You can find a good tutorial here:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: Am not able to play the recorded video(even in chrome) and also, i need to save the video to server. Any other solution or any patches to the mentioned script?

Answer (score 1):

The first hit on searching "webcam plugin": http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/
As it is using JavaScript it is easy to include in Rails.

Many others appear in the results ...

Comment: this plugin can capture static images or stream video but it does not seem to support recording video.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the Nimbb widget.  There are a lot of tutorials showing how to embed it into a website.