# Recording Video via webcam on webpage and saving it to server

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, video, windows-phone-8.1

I want to develop a web application where the user can access the webpage and record a video message , and that video message gets saved on the server. The trick is that it must be accessible via any mobile device.

I know there are answers out there like this:
[Video Recording with webcam on a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978578/video-recording-with-webcam-on-a-webpage)

but it does not encompass all devices. I was thinking of using angular JS but it should work on Microsoft windows phone 8/10, android and ios. That is the tricky part.

The solutions I have researched all requires FF or Chrome and neither IOS or Windows mobile comes standard with those. I want to avoid flash as well.

Many thanks.